# What is encrypted home directory?

Tags: encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When installing Ubuntu, I'm given the option of encrypting my home folder — what does this option do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37/when-installing-ubuntu-im-given-the-option-of-encrypting-my-home-folder-what)

When I do a fresh install I am given an option to check the option to encrypt my home directory.
**What is home directory encryption? And how much my performance degrades if I do so? How to do it on a running pc but not through the option given at the installation.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An encrypted home directory is just like an encrypted hard drive. It simply adds a level of encryption to that in order to protect the files in that directory. There is a very negligible performance degradation that is probably so low that you wouldnt even know unless you measured it with a non encrypted directory