# Create secure working environment on USB stick

Tags: live-usb

I want to create an usb stick which contains an ubuntu installation that:

- can be used as a working environment (Covered in: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)) - ie the ubuntu installation on the stick must provide an accessible home folder.
- Is completely encrypted.

I intend to use it as a secure environment to work on sensitive customer data - and also need the system on the stick to be able to connect to the internet. How do I realize the complete usb stick encryption?

I am also very thankfull for any further articles  and ideas on this topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to encrypt the entire disk - and shouldn't need to. If you constrain all the sensitive data to just your home folder than you can select the "Encrypt home folder" option during the setup process. [More on Encrypted home partitions can be found in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37/when-installing-im-given-the-option-of-encrypting-my-home-folder-what-does-th/)