# Is there a way to set a password to access the computer?

Tags: 10.10, gnome

Not the login keyring thing that pops up, but some people are being nosy and using my computer and I'd like to set a password before Ubuntu desktop even loads so people can't access my computer. Is this possible?

Comment: I have a question... did you specify your system to automatically log in on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off "automatic login" in your system preferences.  Unless you have specifically set it up to auto-login, ubuntu will require a password before anyone can use the computer.

Comment: And make sure the guest login is disabled as well.

Answer (score 1):

The **only** way to hide your private data from nosy eyes is using an [encrypted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37/when-installing-im-given-the-option-of-encrypting-my-home-folder-what-does-th/62#62) system as booting with a live CD grants root access to your system and your $HOME directory to anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a boot password (from your BIOS settings) can also help deal with nosy people. It isn't fully secure, as someone could still remove your hard drive and access the files on it, but it you don't want to mess with encryption, a boot password and a login password will keep most people out.