# Acer Aspire installation of Ubuntu as the one and only OS

Tags: acer, aspire-one

I am quite sick of a Win7 limited edition that was pre-installed on my Acer Aspire One 533. I want to have Ubuntu as the only OS on this little thing.

I have tested Ubuntu on a pretty unstable system and I am simply in love with it, despite the fact that I am still on the learning path.

So my questions is how do I format/erase all previous info, including windows files? I am interested in a real cleanup of the drives rather than just a re-partitioning, because I travel every now and then and I want to prevent any personal data remaining on the drives for anyone with recovery knowledge to sniff through.

Thanks in advance for your input and advice.

A.

Answer (score 1):

if u are using the ubuntu cd or a bootable pendrive then you can choose from different types of install.

One of the options there is to use the complete hard disk for ubuntu. Simply selecting this and clicking forward would erase the whole disk, format it to ext4( format used by ubuntu), and install ubuntu in the whole disk. You wont get any oher partitions. Just one with ubuntu in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not delete previous data securely.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the content of your hard drives you will have to boot with a live CD to

- [Erase the content of your partitions in a secure manner](https://askubuntu.com/q/57572/3940). You may want to spare an existing recovery partition from the vendor.

After having done so we can install Ubuntu using an encrypted home to prevent unwanted access in the future:

- [Install Ubuntu with encrypted home](https://askubuntu.com/q/37/3940)

Chose *erase everything* to use the entire hard drive. Chose *somewthing else* to partition manually (e.g. in case there is a Windows recovery partition you want to keep).