# Does encrypting home folder during the installation also encrypt other user's home folder after the fact?

Tags: filesystem, encryption

If I were to select the option to encrypt my home folder when installing Ubuntu, then does Ubuntu automatically encrypt other user's home folder that I create after I installed Ubuntu?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/37/when-installing-im-given-the-option-of-encrypting-my-home-folder-what-does-t  Also : http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7568/1/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer IMHO is yes. But the encryption actually takes place on the fly when your new user logs in and creates files.