# Encrypt home directory / LVM encryption - Ubuntu Server 14.04 setup

Tags: encryption, lvm

There seems to be two different steps in the Ubuntu Server 14.04 installation that involve encryption. The first asks if I want to encrypt my home directory:

[image]

The second has an option for encrypted LVM:

[image]

Are these two different encryption procedures? If I do both is my drive doubly encrypted? Why would I do one and not the other?

I don't think this is a duplicate of [When installing I'm given the option of encrypting my home folder -- what does this do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37/when-installing-im-given-the-option-of-encrypting-my-home-folder-what-does-t) because that solution does not explain why there are seemingly two encryption steps being offered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are completely separate and other then "encryption" they have nothing in common.

### LUKS

[LUKS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system) / [LVM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LVM) encrypts everything but `/boot`.

With LUKS, almost everything is decrypted when you boot, `/swap`, `/home`, `/`, etc. You can of course configure this differently, but this is how the defaults work.

### eCryptfs

[eCryptfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ECryptfs) or ecryptfs, in contrast, usually encrypts `/home/username`.

With ecryptfs, your home directory is decrypted when you log in. You would use this when you need to encrypt your personal data in `/home` separately from the system.

---

See:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome
- [When installing I'm given the option of encrypting my home folder -- what does this do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37/when-installing-im-given-the-option-of-encrypting-my-home-folder-what-does-t)

Comment: Does it make sense to use both?

Comment: Only on a multi user system