# Automatically Login for All Users

Tags: login, login-screen, auto-login

I don't know, whether this is possible, but...

Since I have lvm-encrypted my entire disk, I see no reason to type another password to login right after startup. However, at the moment I have two user accounts on my laptop. One for business and one for private stuff. I like things separated like this.

Is there a way, I can enable password-free login after startup for both accounts? I mean in such a way that I can choose the account. I don't want to remove my user password.

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04, but I think, this shouldn't be any different to Ubuntu, since both use LightDM.

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
doublerainbow64

Comment: I am not sure if this will work on Kubuntu 14.04, but this [how to seems to do exactly what you want.](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/login-without-a-password-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passphrase you enter on boot is to decrypt the LVM encryption done with LUKS, which is useful if your physical drive is stolen (e.g. your laptop is lifted). That encryption protects your system, but does nothing to protect individual users once the machine is booted and the passphrase has cleared.

If you had passwordless login for any user account, then after boot there would be nothing stopping anyone from accessing and/or modifying your files (and if you have sudo priviledges, this is particularly undesirable). This is very bad if you have a laptop (you're at a coffeeshop and it gets stolen or you lose it at the airport, already booted but maybe suspended, the finder/taker has free reign on your file system).

Basically, I'm saying what you want to do is a bad idea, from a security perspective. The easiest way to do it, I would guess, would be to simply remove your user passwords, and as far as I can see any other solution would amount to doing just that.

You may find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514334/encrypt-home-directory-lvm-encryption-ubuntu-server-14-04-setup) useful for some clarification on LVM encryption.

Comment: I'm absolutely familiar with all this. Definitely, I don't want to remove user passwords.I don't see a problem in this. It may be true that my system would be 'vulnerable' right after boot up. However, whenever I leave my laptop unattended, I would like to lock session, requesting password as usual. Isn't this possible?