# Does the server ISO support installation to a LUKS container?

Tags: system-installation, preseed

Walking through a manual installation using the server URL, I do see the option to install on LVM, but I don't see any option to encrypt it. I mean to use `d-i partman-auto/method string crypto` in a preseed file. Does the server ISO support encrypted installations, or not?

Comment: It does. See [Encrypt home directory / LVM encryption - Ubuntu Server 14.04 setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514334/encrypt-home-directory-lvm-encryption-ubuntu-server-14-04-setup)

Comment: Alright. I retract my close vote but leave my earlier comment for reference.

Comment: You're mostly right.  The problem I had is that I downloaded the server ISO download is now a "live server" which, as far as I can tell, cannot install to an encrypted volume.

What I needed was the "server" URL that's described as the "traditional installer" on some download pages, or the "alternative installer" on others.  It's available on several download pages I've checked, but it's always a small text link and not the big green download button.

Use this link:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer

Comment: there now are two server installers. See Release notes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028580/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-18-04-server-and-ubuntu-18-04-live-server/1028610#1028610 & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes